# rules iptables limit connection by second

Tags: linux, iptables, rules

Hello I have this rule:

`-I INPUT -m string --hex-string "|XXX|" --algo bm --dport 7777 -j DROP`

work's but there is some false positive.

So I want to limit this rule to 5 connections accepted by second before to drop the rest AND if the ip is already connected ( +1 limit), accept other packets with the even ip.

Thanks to help.

Answer (score 1):

UDP does not have any concept of connections, but you can limit to a number of packets per second by using the limit module: `-m limit --limit 5/second`

Even though UDP does not have any concept of connections, iptables still perform connection tracking on UDP packets in the most typical configurations. For that reason it can make a difference if the `limit` rule is used before or after another rule matching on `state`.

Comment: thanks but I edited my post:  "So I want to limit this rule to 5 connections accepted by second before to drop the rest AND if the ip is already connected ( +1 limit), accept other packets with the even ip." so -I INPUT -p udp -m ttl --ttl-eq XXX -m string --hex-string "|XXX|" --algo bm --dport 7777 -m limit --limit 5/second -j DROP  or accept? and for to accept the ip connected?